# Get value from agent failed: TCP successful, cannot establish TLS to ][0.0.0.0]:10050]: connection closed by peer

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

The color of ZBX Availability is changing into red from green and getting following error message on Zabbix Active Check monitoring:

"Get value from agent failed: TCP successful, cannot establish TLS to ][0.0.0.0]:10050]: connection closed by peer"

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Zabbix supports encrypted communications TLS protocol v.1.2.
I think your agent is rejecting the connections. You can look at its log  `/var/log/zabbix-agent/zabbix_agentd.log` to see the deatils.

Also you can check the version of the OpenSSL library on the agent:

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
```

If you have an outdated version - you should update it.

Comment: Hi @banzayats, Thanks for your response. I have updated the OpenSSL to 1.1.0e but the problem is still same. The log shows: 
active check data upload to [zabbix server IP:10051] is working again
active check configuration update from [zabbix server IP: 10051] is working again
active check data upload to [zabbix server IP:10051] started to fail ([connect] TCP successful, cannot establish TLS to [[Zabbix server IP: 10051]: SSL_connect() timed out)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @AlwaysALearner, according to logs your zabbix-agent cannot connect to the server on port 10051.

You can try it manually:

    `telnet zabbix_server_ip 10051`

Check the Zabbix server settings or firewall rules.

Comment: Hi @banzayats, telnet and nc both can connect to the server on both 10050 and 10051 ports. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, also in zabbix_agentd.log:

> failed to accept an incoming connection: from : TLS
>   connections are not allowed

It worked for me again only doing a service restart:

```
service zabbix-agent restart
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case for the same error, PSK Identity Was Incorrect, I Just fixed it and its Working Fine Now.